# How do I scrape a website that ignores my headers?

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests

```
test_url = 'https://crimegrade.org/safest-places-in-60629/'

test_headers = {
    'accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-encoding' : 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'cookie': '_ga=GA1.2.1384046872.1654177894; _gid=GA1.2.924008640.1654177894',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'referer' : 'https://crimegrade.org/crime-by-zip-code/',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests' : '1',
    'user-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.63 Safari/537.36'
          }

crime_response = requests.get(test_url, headers=test_headers)
print(crime_response.content)
```

I've managed to scrape other websites with a similar approach before, but I haven't been able to get parameters or a clean 200 status code for crimegrade.org. I think that's why I'm getting this response:

```
\<div class="cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error" id="cookie-alert" data-translate="enable_cookies">Please enable cookies.\</div>
```

Do you have any advice on how to solve this?

Comment: Maybe try cloudscraper? `https://github.com/VeNoMouS/cloudscraper`

Comment: It doesn't work, but thank you for listing this tech.

Comment: It use antibot Cloudflare nothing to do with python requests. It works with playwright, when you open real browser and you can scrape it.

Comment: Playwright is a good option for raw scripting, but I'm using Jupyter. Playwright doesn't work with Jupyter on Windows 10. It's important for me since I can showcase the work more easily, so I'll hunt for a similar module.

Answer (score 0):

Through a bit more reading, watching, & hunting on my end, I managed to get around this with a very conventional method of automating my browsing with Selenium. My code is below.

Note: .page_source gives the html data which can be parsed with BeautifulSoup. It is akin to the .content yield in my original post, except it's the information I need.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

crime_url = 'https://crimegrade.org/safest-places-in-73505/'
chrome_driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
chrome_driver.get(crime_url)
crime_html = chrome_driver.page_source
chrome_driver.quit()
```